# WCF Authentication

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, membership

I have a WCF service that uses Membership for security. If I create a Silverlight Business Application It automatically links in with it and authenticates. How do I do the same with Windows Forms, and possibly XNA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's Client Application Services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx.  I think that is what you are looking for.

Client application services make it easy for you to create Windows-based applications that use the Microsoft Ajax login, roles, and profile application services included in the Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions. These services enable multiple Web and Windows-based applications to share user information and user-management functionality from a single server. For example, you can use these services to perform the following tasks:

Comment: Thanks, but is that the best way? That seems like a rather old way, it still uses AMSX webservices and not WCF.